# how to fix “Method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::number does not exist.”

Tags: error-handling, laravel-7, artisan-migrate

**When I use php artisan migrate I receive this message. Can someone help me with this? I searched on the Internet but I didn't find anything that helped me. (I am new in laravel)**

My Table:

```
  <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateSroomsTable extends Migration

{

    /**

     * Run the migrations.

     *

     * @return void

     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('srooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('room_two');
            $table->string('room_three');
            $table->string('room_four');
            $table->string('room_five');
            $table->string('room_six');
            $table->string('room_seven');
            $table->string('room_eight');
            $table->string('room_nine');
            $table->string('room_ten');
            $table->string('room_eleven');
            $table->string('room_twelve');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('srooms');
    }
}`
```

Comment: try to change $table->id(); to $table->increments('id');

Comment: It could be the wrong MySQL port number in your .env file. Check your .env file and make sure the port number matches the same one MySQL is using.

Comment: I have tried but it's not solving. I also used  $table->increments('id'); instead of  $table->id(); but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You declared a column as a number like:

```
[$table->number('')]
```

but you should use

```
[$table->integer('')]
```